# How to stop a service after error?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to gracefully handle errors in my code and stop the service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    oMyObject = new MyObject(args);
    if (oMyObject.RunStartup())
    {

        oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oMyObject.MainLoop));
        oThread.Start();

    }

    base.OnStart(args);

}
```

oMyObject.RunStartup() write an error to the event log and returns false if error.

However, the service isn't stopped and the event log shows "Service started successfully."

How do I exit and stop the service in OnStart() without the event log showing "Service started successfully"?

Comment: [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229005.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing what Oded said.  Throwing and exception and don't catch it is the best way to handle this as of now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried implementing `OnStop()` method instead of trying to detect the stop in the `OnStart()` method?

You should then be able to create a `ServiceController` instance and check the `Status` property of the service.

**Edit:** Sorry this is an extension to @Lloyd answer (can't leave comment).

---

**Update:**

Actually thinking about it just adding a `Try` `Catch` block to your `OnStart()` should be enough to catch the exception (see @Oded comment on OP) and allow you to close the service and log to the event log how you see fit.

Comment: Solution is not to catch the exception, but throwing it and not catching it.  What I'm trying to do is exiting the service with an error, not handling the error.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall you can call `Stop()`, such as:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    oMyObject = new MyObject(args);

    if (!oMyObject.RunStartup()) {
        Stop();
        return;
    }

    oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oMyObject.MainLoop));
    oThread.Start();

    base.OnStart(args);

}
```

See here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.stop.aspx

Comment: Problem here is that the event log says "Service stopped successfully" when in fact it stopped because of an error.

Comment: Raise an exception then rather and return true or false.